# Same pygame event generated over and over

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

In my pygame application, I want a web browser to open when the user presses the F1 key:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pygame as pg
import webbrowser

pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((400, 400))
pg.key.set_repeat(200, 100)
while True:
    for evt in pg.event.get():
        if evt.type == pg.KEYDOWN and evt.key == pg.K_F1:
            webbrowser.open('http://some-website.com')
pg.quit()
```

When pressing F1, the browser opens but my application keeps opening new tabs if I don't kill it.  My guess is that the same `KEYDOWN` event is generated over and over when my application loses the focus due to the use of `pg.key.set_repeat`: if I comment this call to `pg.key.set_repeat` then everything works fine.

How can I fix that?

Versions used are: `pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.9.5)`.

Comment: You might be able to trigger a key release on `ACTIVEEVENT`

Comment: @mousetail thanks for the suggestion. i'll have a look at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `keyboard` module like this:

```
import keyboard

# [...]

while True:

# [...]

    if keyboard.is_pressed("F1"):      
        webbrowser.open('http://some-website.com')
pg.quit()
```

Or you can break the loop after you open the spesific website:

```
# [...]

while True:
    for evt in pg.event.get():
        if evt.type == pg.KEYDOWN and evt.key == pg.K_F1:
            webbrowser.open('http://some-website.com')
            break

# [...]

pg.quit()
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I'll give it a try.  For the second solution however, the `webrowser.open` is not directly in the main loop but in some function. So I would then have to e.g. raise an exception and break if the exception is raised.